# How to check an empty date argument in a XQuery function?

Tags: xquery

Consider the following code which checks for an empty date:

```
declare xqse function tns:isEmptyDate($dob as xs:date) as xs:boolean {
    if(empty($dob)) then {
    }
}
```

When executed, why do I get the below error in ALDSP:

> `weblogic.xml.query.exceptions.XQueryDynamicException: {err}XP0021: "": can not cast to {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}date: error: date: Invalid date value: wrong type:`

Answer (score 2):

OK, I've had a look at this and I think you'll be able to run your query by defining your function as

```
declare function tns:isEmptyDate($dob as xs:date?) as xs:boolean
```

Note the ? after the type - it means that the argument may be the empty sequence.

I tested this out in Oxygen, using Saxon-B... sorry, I don't have access to the software you're using.

Here's my function definition.

```
declare function tns:isEmptyDate($dob as xs:date?) as xs:boolean {
    let $empty := if (empty($dob))
        then true()
        else false()
    return $empty
};
```

Running against this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datetime>2002-09-24</datetime>
```

returns true, and running against this file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dontmatch>2002-09-24</dontmatch>
```

returns false.

Running the same function without the questionmark, on the second document, errors with:

> Severity: error. Description: An empty sequence is not allowed as the first argument of tns:isEmptyDate()

Answer (score 1):

Try this with a question mark or star after the type declaration.

E.g.,

$dob as xs:date
means $dob is a sequence of 1 item (of type xs:date)

$dob as xs:date?
means $dob is a sequence of 1 or none items (each of which are of type xs:date)

$dob as xs:date*
means $dob is a sequence of none or more items (each of which are of type xs:date)

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `empty()` instead of writing your own function.  Empty will return true if a sequence has count zero, where `xs:date?` can be a sequence of length zero or one.

Answer (score 0):

I've only tinkered with XQuery, but I suspect that the error is being generated because the function signature `($dob as xs:date)` requires a date type and you're passing something else e.g. an empty value.